# Resources Root Directory converted into Test Resources Root After Adding JMH Plugin (IntelliJ Scala)

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, intellij-scala, sbt-jmh

I'm trying to add JMH Plugin in Scala Project (Intellij Idea). I'm doing this by adding plugin in `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("pl.project13.scala" % "sbt-jmh" % "0.4.3")
```

Then enabling that plugin in `build.sbt`:

```
ThisBuild / version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"

ThisBuild / scalaVersion := "2.13.4"

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .settings(
    name := "my-project"
  )

ThisBuild / scapegoatVersion := "1.4.8"

enablePlugins(JmhPlugin)
```

But when I build the project, it converts my `src/main/resources` (Resources Root) folder to (Test Resources Root). After this I'm unable to access the contents in the config files which were in my `src/main/resources`. If I delete plugin of JMH then again everything works fine.

Guide me why is it so and how can I avoid this?

Comment: You mean in IntelliJ the folder is marked as "test resources root"? Sounds weird, maybe open an issue at Jetbrains?

Comment: Anyway you can manually fix it and mark the folder as the proper kind.

Comment: @GaëlJ
Ok I'll open an issue at Jetbrains. But how can I manually mark this folder as the proper kind do this?

Comment: Right click on a folder, "Mark as".